# What are some simple custom modules to play with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, learn-magento

I'm learning Magento 2 modules. I would like to create custom modules from beginner level to advanced.

Can you please tell me what are simple concepts that can be created as a module in Magento 2?

Also, Is it possible to create price slider in category page without using any extension?

Looking your valuable comments and answer.

Comment: As you donot want to use any extension  then you have to  build your module for implement `create price slider in category page without using any extension`

Comment: Also what you question ,  `create simple module` or ` create price slider in category page without using any extension. Can Question does NOT have two different purposes? User will get confused when  trying to answer.

Comment: @AmitBera, You're right. I will separate the questions. Can you please suggest how to build module for price slider?